# How to use Foundation CSS dropdown list for ajax search results

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm just trying out using a Foundation dropdown list to show ajax search results from a text input field. Is there any way to do this? I just want to use the style of the dropdown list to format my search results.

I started just by trying to simply put a dropdown list on the page and see if I can get it to be visible without needing to click on a dropdown or other target, but the list refuses to show.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search">
<ul class="f-dropdown open f-dropdown-open content" data-dropdown-content>
    <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Disclaimer:** I don't know Foundation much yet, I'm trying to modify someone else's UI.

I was planning on just rendering the page with the dropdown hidden by default with an additional `hide` class, and then after my ajax request populate the list inside before basically doing a jQuery `.show()` on the dropdown `<ul>`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need this code so it can re-apply the listeners to dropdowns. You will need to add class `.open` to show it.

```
$(document).foundation('dropdown', 'reflow');
```

Comment: It doesn't need to reapply any listeners, the dropdown is already there on page load. And it has `open` class already - it doesn't work, it's still hidden due to other CSS which is only removed by the Foundation JS when you toggle a dropdown from a button.